How to access private repo shared with my account using a Github fine-grained personal access token?
I'm using the Github API via Octokit, like so:
import { Octokit } from  '@octokit/rest';

const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,
});

I have set the value of the GITHUB_TOKEN env var using a fine grained PAT,
with every read-only permission set,
and with the repository access for this PAT is set to "All repositories. This applies to all future repositories you own. Also includes public repositories (read-only)."

Running the following code results in a 404 error:
    const user = await octokit.rest.users.getAuthenticated();
    console.log(`Authenticated as: ${user.data.login}`);

    console.log('Collaborators for', repoOwner, repoName);
    const repoCollaborators = await octokit.repos.listCollaborators({
        owner: repoOwner,
        repo: repoName,
    });
    console.log(repoCollaborators.data.map(collaborator => collaborator.login));


Note that I'm trying to access a private repo from a different Github account,
that has been shared with my account.
The PAT is for my account.
My account has full read and access in the Github web UI,
as well as over git+SSH.
The error encountered from running the above code is:
GET /repos/bguiz/hdc-test-repo/collaborators - 404 with id 30FB:353D7F:2130080:259B2E8:6756B1E4 in 323ms
An error occurred: Not Found - https://docs.github.com/rest/collaborators/collaborators#list-repository-collaborators

I then tried the (not recommended) Classic PAT,
which has all the repo scope settings set,
and nothing else set.

Interestingly, I do not get the same result if I instead use this classic PAT,
and the API request goes through.
I would like to use the fine-grained PAT instead,
since this is recommended.
How can I do so?
